# Run Powershell Cmdlet with various number of parameters

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm scripting some configuration of Azure Analysis Service, and more specifically the firewall. The cmdlet

```
New-AzAnalysisServicesFirewallConfig -FirewallRule
```

takes in the rules created as a parameter; `$rule1` as an example.

I want the script to be able to take a varying number of parameters to that command. Instead of having to hardcode it to X number of rules like in the example with 6 rules.

I tried to create an Array and a Hashtable containing the X number of parameters, but it's unable to convert them.

```
$FirewallRules | ForEach-Object {
    $ruleNumberVar = "rule" + "$ruleNumberIndex"

    if (!($_.FirewallRuleName -match "$ExistingFirewallRuleName")) {
        $start = $_.RangeStart
        $end = $_.RangeEnd
        $tempRule = New-AzAnalysisServicesFirewallRule `
                       -FirewallRuleName $_.FirewallRuleName `
                       -RangeStart $start `
                       -RangeEnd $end

        Set-Variable -Name "$ruleNumberVar" -Value $tempRule 
        $ruleNumberIndex = $ruleNumberIndex + 1
    }

    $conf = New-AzAnalysisServicesFirewallConfig -FirewallRule $rule1,$rule2,$rule3,$rule4,$rule5,$rule6
```

Getting this error:

> New-AzAnalysisServicesFirewallConfig : Cannot bind parameter 'FirewallRule'. Cannot convert the "System.Collections.Hashtable" value of type "System.Collectio
>   ns.Hashtable" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.AnalysisServices.Models.PsAzure
>   AnalysisServicesFirewallRule".

Comment: It looks like you need to create a list of those rule types. That code would be something like `$Rules = @() -as [System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.AnalysisServices.Models.PsAzureAnalysisServicesFirewallRule]`. Then use `$Rules.Add($rule1)` to add $rule1 to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested and therefore theoretical, but this should fix that error if the type can be casted.

```
$Rules = @() -as [System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.AnalysisServices.Models.PsAzureAnalysisServicesFirewallRule]]
$FirewallRules | ForEach-Object {
    $ruleNumberVar = "rule" + "$ruleNumberIndex"

    if (!($_.FirewallRuleName -match "$ExistingFirewallRuleName")) {
        $start = $_.RangeStart
        $end = $_.RangeEnd
        $tempRule = New-AzAnalysisServicesFirewallRule `
                       -FirewallRuleName $_.FirewallRuleName `
                       -RangeStart $start `
                       -RangeEnd $end

        Set-Variable -Name $ruleNumberVar -Value $tempRule
        $Rules.Add((Get-Variable $ruleNumberVar -ValueOnly))
        $ruleNumberIndex = $ruleNumberIndex + 1
    }
}
    $conf = New-AzAnalysisServicesFirewallConfig -FirewallRule $Rules
```